# Every run new value in method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have 50 numbers to check if they're active.

For now,  my test open our internal company site, going through some tabs, then I paste phone number and wait for element that cofirm if number is active.

It works when i have 1 or two number to check, C can change this in my method and everything is ok but is there any possibility to automate this when i have 50 numbers to check? Put all numbers in a list and with every run of my code use next number? And then print all active numbers?

I know that for run method multiple times I have to use "@Test(invocationCount = x)" but then? I don't have idea, list sounds reasonably

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"mainCtrl\"]/header/div[1]/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/button[2]")
  private WebElement clickedToSearchNumber;

public void typeNumber(String number) {
      typeNumber.sendKeys(number);

  }

activationProces activation = new activationProces(driver);
      activation.typeNumber("123123123");
```

Comment: Why not just read the numbers from a text file, loop over them and check them?

Comment: So I wrote some code, by scanner I'm reading a file and using while (sc.hasNextLine()) iterating through every line and printing all numbers. But how to iterate to next number with every run of loop? I mean first run - first number from first line, second run second number second line etc etc

Comment: You will need to post more of your code. You just have part of a class. We really need to see the entire code you have written that reads the file, loops and interacts with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class file {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    File file =
            new File("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\number.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

 while (sc.hasNextLine())
     System.out.println(sc.nextLine());}  }
```

So this code reads numbers from my file